# Does a NSData image weight in memory as much as the opened image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am doing an upload function to my server from my iOS app. I am right now architecting the best way to do this and thinking that my approach would run into trouble.

I've over 20 pictures that I would like to send in 1 request using `AFmultiparFormData` in `AFNetworking` with also text information that is relevant to that picture.

Now... I know how to create the `NSDictionary` with lots of information inside but never created a `NSDictionary` with 20 images in `NSData` format or attempted to upload many pictures at once.

The issue is that I don't know whether the `NSData` images would take as much memory space as an image. Thus, I could only do 2/3 at the time (if they were full screen images which they are not, but its just an arbitrary point of measurement)

Given What I said and the seudo code below, Could I do that or would I ran out of memory? otherwise I would be left to do 1 by 1.

```
// for loop that does this 20 times
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:myExercise.exercisePictureThumb];
NSData * exercisePictureThumb = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);

// add to dictionary recursively
```

Comment: as I said I am architecting it... testing it would mean implementation...

Comment: Make a bare-bones program, feed it some images, and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not put all of your image data into a `NSDictionary`, as that's likely to cause memory problems.

Instead, create a dictionary or array of the URLs to your files, then make use of AFNetworking's [`multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.2.1/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/multipartFormRequestWithMethod%3apath%3aparameters%3aconstructingBodyWithBlock%3a) and the [`AFMultipartFormData protocol`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.2.1/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html), particularly `appendPartWithFileURL:name:fileName:mimeType:error:`. This way your image data for all of the images is not all in memory at one time, but is instead streamed from disk. Huge performance increase.

Comment: There is already virtual memory that takes care of this problem, so I wouldn't care so much about transfering stuff from RAM to disk and viceversa. Is enough to release parts of memory when you receive a memory warning in the app delegate.

Comment: The better approach is to be careful of how much memory your app is using. I've been in situations where `didReceiveMemoryWarning` wasn't enough to save the app from being jettisoned. If you can avoid having 20 images' worth of data in memory, I'd say do so.

Comment: @MishieMoo so in fileURL i put the full path to the file?

Comment: Exactly. Make sure to create it with `[NSURL fileURLWithString...]` though, as otherwise the file wont' be read correctly.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri There is no virtual memory swapping happening on iOS devices. Thus, making sure you don't load the images into memory at one time is a very important consideration on devices. MishieMoo is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

MishieMoo is absolutely right regarding the memory/streaming considerations and the wise counsel to avoid loading all of the images into memory at one time.

I wanted to get back to your `UIImage` vs `NSData` question, though. In my mind, there are two considerations:

1. **File size:** Unfortunately, there is no simple answer as to whether the original image will be smaller than the `UIImage`/`UIImagePNGRepresentation` output. Sometimes, if the original file was a JPEG, the result of round-tripping the image through a `UIImage` can actually make the file larger (e.g. I just grabbed three images and the PNG roundtrip took them from 4.7mb to 38.9mb). But, if the originals were uncompressed images, then the PNG roundtrip could make them considerably smaller.
2. **Data loss:** For me, the more significant issue with round-tripping the image through `UIImage` is that you'll suffer data loss. You lose meta data. Depending upon the image, you can even lose image data in the translation, too (e.g. if original wasn't in sRGB color space, if bit-depth lowered, etc.).

Now, sometimes it makes perfect sense (e.g., I use a variation of this `UIImage` round trip technique when creating image thumbnails). But if my intent is to upload images onto a server, I'd be very wary about going through the `UIImage` conversion, possibly losing data, without a compelling business case.